# How to plot a complex-valued function of a real variable in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was trying to plot the function `((phi^n)-((-1/phi)^n))/(5^0.5)` as the real part in the x-axis and imaginary part in the y-axis with matplotlib and numpy, I used this code to do so

```
#matplotlib.pyplot for the graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#numpy for mathematical operations 
from numpy import arange, real, imag, sin, cos
#phi is just a mathematical constant
phi = (1+(5**0.5))/2
#x, the domain
x = arange(0,5,0.01)
#f, the function
def f(x):
    return ((phi**(x))-((-1/phi)**(x)))/(5**0.5)
#labels for x and y axes
plt.xlabel('real')
plt.ylabel('imag')
#plot the actual graph with the label
plt.plot(real(f(x)),imag(f(x)), label='((phi**(x))-((-1/phi)**(x)))/(5**0.5)')
#show the label
plt.legend()
#show the graph
plt.show()
```

However, the error `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power return ((phi**(x))-((-1/phi)**(x)))/(5**0.5)` appears to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot a complex-valued function of a real variable you have to specify that the range of the function is complex numbers so that NumPy arrays are able to store complex numbers. You can do this by adding `+0j` to the function's variable, so the code will be like this

```
#matplotlib.pyplot for the graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#numpy for mathematical operations 
from numpy import arange, real, imag, sin, cos
#phi is just a mathematical constant
phi = (1+(5**0.5))/2
#x, the domain
x = arange(0,5,0.01)
#f, the function (notice the 'x+0j' part)
def f(x):
    return ((phi**(x+0j))-((-1/phi)**(x+0j)))/(5**0.5)
#labels for x and y axes
plt.xlabel('real')
plt.ylabel('imag')
#plot the actual graph with the label
plt.plot(real(f(x)),imag(f(x)), label='((phi**(x))-((-1/phi)**(x)))/(5**0.5)')
#show the label
plt.legend()
#show the graph
plt.show()
```